# Can .profile file be deleted in a Linux system?

Tags: linux, user-accounts, user-profiles, user

I recently added a user account in linux system. The system created a folder with the user name and also a file called .profile within the folder.

My question is this. Can it be deleted and the user still have full access to his folder?

Comment: The existence of the file doesn't determine access to the user's home folder, but it does (typically) have things that set up the environment during shell startup for interactive logins.  If you are using bash and the user is a non-interactive user there shouldn't be any issue with removing .profile.

Comment: You should find the version used in `/etc/skel`, as normally for each new user, the contents  of it is copied into the new users home directory. This means, if you don't like what the system is doing, then you can change the file in `/etc/skel` beforehand or even delete it.